# searching the specific context name in asterisk dial plan

Tags: asterisk

Is there a way to directly access the specific context name in asterisk dialplan while i 
am using vim editor for asterisk dialplan, i could remember that some command with \ is 
used but don't know what exactly that was. thanks for your help

Comment: Why don't you accept answers?

Answer (score 0):

It is forward slash to search through the file

/search-term